# How to make the computer consider two numbers equal up to a certain precision

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

My problem is that I have a matrix `A` and the computer says is not Hermitian (self-adjoint). Then I check which elements make `A` be not Hermitian by calculating:

```
B=A-ConjugateTranspose[A]
```

In case `A` is Hermitian, this difference should be zero. What I get is that `A` is not Hermitian, but the terms I get in matrix `B` all are smaller than `10^(-15)`.

So how can I fix it at the beggining of the code, *Mathematica* to consider two numbers equal, up to `10^(-10)` precision for example, that is it to consider:

> 0.00000000010 = 0.00000000012

or saying it in an alternative way, I want *Mathematica* to consider the following matrix Hermitian:

```
C={{0,I*1.1^(-10)},{-I*1.2^(-10),0}}
```

throughout the whole code.

Comment: You can force it to consider c Hermetian by instead using `cHerm=1/2(c + ConjugateTranspose[c])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check to see if the difference is less than the desired amount, and if so, to force it to be symmetric:

```
c = {{0, I 1.1*10^(-10)}, {-I 1.2*10^(-10), 0}}; 
cOut = If[Abs[Total[c - ConjugateTranspose[c], 2]] < 10^(-10), 
           1/2 (c + ConjugateTranspose[c]),c]
```

This returns `cOut` which is a symmetrized version of `c` if `c` is close to Hermetian and returns `c` otherwise (i..e, if it really isn't Hermetian).

Answer (score 23):

There are two undocumented functions which control the tolerance of `Equal` and `SameQ`: `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` and `` Internal`$SameQTolerance ``. I refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626748/590388) answer of mine for further information.

Comment: Accidentally hit touch-screen and downvoted. Will reverse when timeout happens. Sorry.

Comment: @rasher Moderators cannot change votes. You can make a dummy edit, reverse your vote and then undo the edit within the minute. (there will be a note in the history that you edited the post, but the contents will remain the same)