# Machine Epsilon

Tags: numerics, machine-precision, number-representation

I'm trying to evaluate the [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) of my computer (see below). I wrote this:

```
eps = 1.0;
p = 0;
While[(1.0 + eps) > 1.0, eps = eps/2.0; p += 1];
eps
p
eps*2
```

and got:

```
1.42109*10^-14
46
2.84217*10^-14
```

which is not what I expected ([IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)). So I did this

```
EngineeringForm[1.0 + 2 * eps, 20]
EngineeringForm[1.0 + eps, 20]
EngineeringForm[1.0 + (eps/2.0), 20]
EngineeringForm[1.0 + (eps/4.0), 20]
EngineeringForm[1.0 + (eps/16.0), 20]
EngineeringForm[1.0 + (eps/32.0), 20]
```

and got that:

```
1.000000000000028
1.000000000000014
1.000000000000007
1.000000000000004
1.000000000000001
1.
```

which seems to contradict the termination condition of the 'while' loop. So I would like to understand what's going on under *Mathematica's* hood. I tried to look for some information on *Mathematica's* internal float representation without success. Any help to explain these results is welcome. I'm sorry if my question is a bit vague.

Eric

Context:

```
SystemInformationData[{"Kernel" ->
    {"Version" -> "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)", 
    "ReleaseID" -> "9.0.1.0 (4055646, 4055073)", ...}]
```

EDIT

It was suggested the following program that works directly for some reason:

```
eps = 1.0;
n = 0;
While[(1.0 + eps) - 1.0 > 0.0,
  eps = eps/2;
  n++;
];
eps*2
n
Log[2, eps*2]
```

Comment: How about `$MachineEpsilon`?

Comment: Hmm, yes. That gives 2.22045*10^-16 which is yet another value. Besides, I was asked to 'calculate' the machine's epsilon not just provide the value. Thx for the feedback.

Comment: Try `1. + $MachineEpsilon > 1.`...

Comment: As per [reference doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$MachineEpsilon.html), this is indeed corresponds to 2^(-n+1) with n=53, which is the mantissa of a double precision IEEE754 float. That's what I expected. I still don't understand why the while loop calculation did not give this result.

Comment: @MichaelE2, tried that and got: In[439]:= 1.0 + $MachineEpsilon > 1.0
Out[439]= False. If I'm not wrong, this should have been True, no?

Comment: To comment on my last comment above, this test works: `(1.0 + $MachineEpsilon) - 1.0 > 0.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a tolerance `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` that is applied when testing `Real` numbers.    If the numbers agree up to the last `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` digits, then they are treated as equal.  Try this:

```
eps = 1.0;
p = 0;
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0.},
 While[(1.0 + eps) > 1.0, eps = eps/2.0; p += 1];
 ]
eps
p
eps*2
(*
  1.11022*10^-16
  53
  2.22045*10^-16
*)
```

See [How to make the computer consider two numbers equal up to a certain precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35089/how-to-make-the-computer-consider-two-numbers-equal-up-to-a-certain-precision/35094#35094) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica/6626748#6626748) by [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov).

Comment: Ah, beautiful! Thx Michael! This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica) was also useful. Sorry I can't vote yet ;-). Eric

Comment: @Eric You're welcome. :)