# Accuracy of Mod[x, 1] and FractionalPart[x]

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

The difference between exact and numerical computation is clear to me. But why is

```
{7.2 - 7 == 8.2 - 8, 
8.2 - 8 == 9.2 - 9,
(7.2 - 7) - (8.2 - 8) > 0, 
(8.2 - 8) - (9.2 - 9) == 0}
```

equal to

```
{True, True, True, True}
```

(same behavior with `Mod[n + 0.2, 1]`and `FractionalPart[n + 0.2]`)

and why has `(n + 0.2) - n` $12$ different values when the integer $n$ runs from $0$ to $10^6$? Indeed

```
Tally[Table[(n + .2) - n, {n, 0, 10^6}]] // Length
```

gives `12`. Only `(n + 0.) - n` and `(n + 0.5) - n` always give the same answer.

Comment: This is controlled by ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` (see e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48810), among others).

Comment: The second question is because the machine real representation of a decimal input is the nearest fraction of the form $a / 2^p$, where $a$ is an integer with $1 \le a < 2^53$ (as long as the decimal number is not too big or too small in absolute value).  When a number like `0.2` that is not a power of of the form `b / 2^q` (in a certain range) is subtracted, the round-off changes with `n` somewhat. Note `(n + 0.375) - n` gives the same answer too up to around `5 * 10^15`.  Try `Table[(n + 0.5) - n, {n, 1*10^15, 1*10^16, 10^15}]` to see a change in round-off,

Answer (score 3):

Two insightful responses were left in comments which I think are worth summarizing here as answers:

- As [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-s-ennui) mentioned, `Equal` has a tolerance within which the two arguments are considered equal. This is controlled by `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` (see e.g. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48810), among [others](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%24EqualTolerance)).
- Regarding the second question, [Michael](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) mentioned that the machine real representation of a decimal input is the nearest fraction of the form $a/2^p$, where $a$ is an integer with $1≤a<2^{53}$ (as long as the decimal number is not too big or too small in absolute value). When a number like `0.2` that is not of the form `b / 2^q` (with `q` relatively small, such as `1/2 == 0.5` or `3/8 == 0.375`) — when it is added from `n`, the round-off error changes with `n` somewhat.  Note `(n + 0.375) - n` gives the same answer too up to around `5 * 10^15`. Try `Table[(n + 0.5) - n, {n, 1*10^15, 1*10^16, 10^15}]` to see a change in round-off.

Answer (score 0):

From the help of `Equal`:

"Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)."

Note, that "their last 2 decimal digits"  must be interpreted by taking into account. that ending zeros are not written and that machine numbers have approx. 16 decimal digits.

Now considering the first 4 questions that give `True`. If we write LHS and RHS separately:

```
{{7.2 - 7, 8.2 - 8}, {8.2 - 8, 
   9.2 - 9}, {(7.2 - 7), (8.2 - 8)}, {(8.2 - 8), (9.2 - 
     9)}} // FullForm
```

[image]

We see, that they differ at most by the 2 last decimal digits and are therefore considered equal.

On the other hand, the  question with `Tally`:
From the help of `Tally`:

"Tally[list] is equivalent to Tally[list,SameQ]."

And from the help of `SameQ`:

"SameQ requires exact correspondence between expressions, except that it still considers Real numbers equal if they differ in their last binary digit."

`SameQ` is therefore more stringent than `Equal`. Additionally, remember that this corresponds to approx. 16 decimal digits with machine numbers. If we write both terms to be subtracted separately:

Tally[Table[{(n + 0.2) - n}, {n, 0, 10^6}]][[All, 1]] // FullForm

We get:

[image]

And we see that these values differ more than the 16.th decimal digits.