# RegionMember with some tolerance?

Tags: numerics, regions, expression-test

Can I specify some tolerance for the new geometric-computation function?

```
RegionMember[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], {.5, 0}]
(* True *)
```

While:

```
RegionMember[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 10^-100}}], {.5, 0}]
(* False *)

RegionMember[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 10.^-100}}], {.5, 0}]
(* True *)

RegionMember[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 10.^-7}}], {.5, 0}]
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `` Internal`$EqualTolerance ``.  See [How to make the computer consider two numbers equal up to a certain precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35089/how-to-make-the-computer-consider-two-numbers-equal-up-to-a-certain-precision/35094#35094) and its reference.

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 9.},
 RegionMember[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 10.^-7}}], {.5, 0}]
 ]
(* True *)
```

It's a relative tolerance, whereas gpap's & kguler's answers give absolute ones.  The setting above, which is roughly equivalent to `` Internal`$EqualTolerance = $MachinePrecision - 7 ``, says approximate numbers that agree to seven digits (or differ in at most the last nine) are to be considered equal.

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = $MachinePrecision - 7},
 {1. + 1.0000001*^-7 == 1, 1. + 1*^-7 == 1}
 ]
(* {False, True} *)
```

Comment: Yes, this, temporarily overriding the equality criteria, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Upvote for trick..

Answer (score 7):

This (or an appropriately written variant) works:

```
myRegionMember[a_, b_] := With[{threshold = 10^-6},
  If[
   RegionDistance[a, b] < threshold,
   True,
   False
   ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
f1 = RegionDistance[#, #2] < #3]&

f1[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 10.^-7}}], {.5, 0}, 10^-6]
(* True *)

f2 = Chop[RegionDistance[#, #2] ,#3] == 0&

f2[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 10.^-7}}], {.5, 0}, 10^-6]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [gpap's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63378/6555):

```
Options[regionMember] = {Tolerance -> 0};

regionMember[reg_Line, p : {_?NumberQ, _?NumberQ},
  OptionsPattern[]] :=
 With[{e = OptionValue[Tolerance]},
  If[e == 0, RegionMember[reg, p], RegionDistance[reg, p] < e]]

line = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}];
ps = {.5, #} & /@ {0, 10^-100, 10.^-16, 10.^-5};

regionMember[line, #] & /@ ps
(* {True, False, False, False} *)

regionMember[line, #, Tolerance -> 10.^-6] & /@ ps
(* {True, True, True, False} *)
```