# Configurable tolerance for numerical equality?

Tags: undocumented, expression-test

In standard C++ the double values for 1. + 1.2*^-16 and 1. are not considered equal. But in Mathematica, I get the following:

```
With[{aux = 1 + 1.2*^-16}, 
 {{1 == aux, 1. == aux}, {1 < aux, 1. < aux}, {ArcSin[aux], ArcSin[1.]}}]
```

returns

```
{{True, True}, {False, False}, {1.5708 - 2.10734*10^-8 I, 1.5708}}
```

Is there a parameter that I can set, to get the behaviour as in C++, i.e. strict floating point equality?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See
[How to make the computer consider two numbers equal up to a certain precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35089/how-to-make-the-computer-consider-two-numbers-equal-up-to-a-certain-precision/35094#35094)
and the linked [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6626748) for more details.
This question is similar to the first one, except the OP here wants the tolerance to be $-\infty$, instead of greater.

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = -∞},
 1 + $MachineEpsilon == 1.
 ]
1 + $MachineEpsilon == 1.
(*
  False
  True
*)
```

Comment: Perhaps this question should be considered a duplicate?

Comment: For zero bits tolerance, `Internal\`$EqualTolerance` should be `-Infinity`. A value of `0` leaves 1 bit tolerance.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks.  I misremembered how it works.