# A pattern replacement to force Mathematica to replace inexact 0 multiplication by zero

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, precision-and-accuracy

Hi  Consider the following expression which contains multiplication by inexact 0

```
E^(-0.400000000000000 a - 
  4.45401233327988 b) (1.000000000000 E^(
    0.400000000000000 a + 4.45401233327988 b) + 
   0.*10^-13 E^(0.400000000000000 a + 0.172989402425367 b)
     k + (0.*10^-13 + 0.*10^-13 a) E^(0.172989402425367 b)
     k + (0.*10^-13 + 0.*10^-13 a) E^(4.28102293085451 b)
     k + (0.*10^-13 + 0.*10^-13 a) E^(4.50802466655976 b) k + 
   0.*10^-13 E^(0.400000000000000 a + 4.28102293085451 b) k + 
   0.*10^-13 E^(0.400000000000000 a + 4.50802466655976 b) k)
```

It was produced by

```
Chop[D[Jf[x, a, b], x] /. x -> b] /. {x_Real /; x == 0 -> 0}
```

It's hard to give a complete and simple definition of Jf, but I hope that may not be necessary. Suffice to say Chop did not do his job; it would be nice to have 
some pattern replacement fixup, like /. {x_Real /; x == 0 -> 0} 
(this did not work, of course, since 0.*10^-13 is not 0). I tried also without success

```
(D[Jf[x, a, b], x] /. x -> b) /. {0.*10^-13 -> 0}
```

Comment: "Chop did not do his job" - why not adjust the *second* argument of `Chop[]`, then? `Chop[expr, 1.*^-12]`.

Comment: "Chop did not do his job" - nah, you just did not use it correctly; as @J.M said, there is a reason for the second argument of `Chop`. Note also that `Chop` will work on your final expression to return 1. Since you did not give us the expression for `Jf`, we cannot check the original computation. Also, your pattern replacement comparison `{x_Real /; x == 0 -> 0}` relies on [`Equal`'s internal tolerance for numerical expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35094/27951): you may need to adjust that to your needs, or at least be aware of that. You could also use `PossibleZeroQ`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check numbers for zero precision and replace with 0.

```
foo = x + 1234567`3 - 1234567`3
(* 0.*10^3 + x *)
foo /. x_Real /; Precision[x] <= 0. -> 0
(* x *)
```

Edit:

Another way is to use `SetPrecision` instead of `Chop`. That sets zero precision numbers in the expression to exactly zero.

```
SetPrecision[foo, Infinity]
(* x *)
```

Comment: I had already tried Chop[ , ]  for some reason, it doesn't work. l will add eventually a simplified complete example :)  @John Doty since I do not fully understand "Check numbers for zero precision"  I played this by the ear for a while, but unsuccessfully. Last attempt:  Assuming[{Element[a, Integers], Element[k, Integers], 
  Element[b, Integers]}, 
 FullSimplify[
  D[Jf[x, a, b], x] /. 
    x -> b /. {y_Real /; Precision[y] <= (-12) -> 0}]]

Comment: A number with zero precision displays as something like `0.*10^3`. Its `FullForm` looks like `0``-3.3925446597502456`. Zero precision means that no digits of the number are known. I don't think `Precision` will ever yield a negative number, so your `Precision[y] <= (-12)` will never be satisfied. For your problem, `Precision[x] <= 0` should work.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!  SetPrecision[foo, Infinity]  has done the job. @MarcoB,  for Chop, I had kind of improvement :)  switching  first the order with FullSimplify                     mi = Chop[FullSimplify[D[Jf[x, a, b], x] /. x -> b], 1.*^-12] 
 improved the answer to    1.000000000000 E^(0.*10^-16 a + 0.*10^-15 b)   and rechopping                Chop[mi, 1.*^-12]  got it.  It's interesting that chopping twice may be needed.  Anyway, I'm glad I got your help without needing to explain my function Jf :)